# htaccess deny all IP refers

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ip

My website is getting bombarded with requests that are referred from an IP address.

> [Sat Dec 14 22:03:14 2013] [error] [client XXX.XX.XX.XX] client denied
>   by server configuration: /home/user/public_html/folder/folder/,
>   referer: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/

You see the referrer isn't a domain name like a legit refer would be, instead it's from an IP and it bombards my website thousands of times. I have blocked the IP address and similar ones like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} XXX\.XXX\.XXX [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

But how can I block all referrers coming from an IP address? As far as my website is concerned the vast majority if not every single user will visit my site from a domain refer not IP address. Only a visitor with malicious intent will come vis IP refer as I am experiencing now.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} *\.*\.* [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

I tried this thinking it would work but it doesn't. I thought maybe this would be a wild card for each set of digits. But it gave a large amount of errors in the logs...

Comment: @Floris: Give your answer as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman - it started out shorter, then grew into an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match any string that is formed like an ip address it will look something like

```
[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1-3}\.[0-9]{1,3}
```

the regex for "1 to 3 digits, four times, separated by period". Obviously you could test for just three groups of digits, but that's the general idea.  A shorthand for `[0-9]` is `\d` "any digit" - and since the first three groups are the same (up to three digits followed by period) you can make the expression more compact by grouping them.

That means you might want to try this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  (\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}  [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: Thanks @floris I am too new to having voting privileges to up vote, but I appreciate the help! I will try what you've described.